# Best way to close and shutdown objects in onDestroy

Tags: android, ondestroy

Inside the onDestroy method, whats the correct way to determine if an object was actually initialized before trying to close it/shut it down/etc.

For example, which is better:

```
protected void onDestroy()
{
    if(tts != null)
    {
        tts.shutdown();
    }

    if(dbWord != null)
    {
        dbWord.close();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

or this:

```
protected void onDestroy()
{
    if(tts instanceof  null)
    {
        tts.shutdown();
    }

    if(dbWord instanceof TextToSpeech)
    {
        dbWord.close();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use != instead of instanceOf to check if a variable was initialized.  instanceOf performs additional type checking which you do not need in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `!=`, don't use `instanceOf`. When you declare an object, it's already an instance of some class, even it's not initialized, NULL certainly. 
The first one of yours is correct way to handle.